# SQL Server Geography vs DbGeography

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, geospatial

I have two GPS Coordinates i wanted to calculate distance between those but the result on SQL server is entirely different from result in c# I googled and found that the both approaches return distance in meters but this difference is driving me crazy.

***SQL SERVER Query***

```
select geography::Point(25.3132666, 55.2994054 ,4326)
                         .STDistance(geography::Point(25.25434, 55.32820,4326)) as Distance;
```

[image: Result of above sql query]

***Web API***

```
String format = "POINT(25.25434 55.32820)";
                DbGeography myLocation = DbGeography.PointFromText(format, 4326);
                var users = context.Users.Select(u => new
                {
                    fullName = u.name,
                    lat = u.location.Latitude,
                    lng = u.location.Longitude,
                    distance = myLocation.Distance(u.location)
                }).ToList();
```

***Response***

```
,{"fullName":"jons smith","lat":25.3132666,"lng":55.2994054,"distance":4133581.8647264037}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If to compare directly code in your question we don't know what is the location of the user. In SQL you hardcode some coordinates. I assume they are different than user coordinates.

Comment: Assert both use same  geodetic system (which most probably is WGS 84). Still then I could imagine calculus may differ, e.g. depending on the used earth diameter (Take into account earth isn't a perfect sphere). Just a guess...

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov I pasted only that record from response as a reference which has exactly same values, you can see lat long of record are exactly same as of  of SQL-Query

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check latitude and longitude order in the WKT representation of the point in SQL when defining the point, they are as follow `GEOGRAPHY::POINT(Latitude, Longitude, srid)`:

```
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::Point(25.3132666,55.2994054 ,4326)
                    .STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point(25.25434, 55.32820,4326)) as distance;
//distance: 7142.94965953253
```

**But when defining `DBGeography` in C# code, the order is different:`"POINT(Longitude Latitude)"`**

```
String format = "POINT(55.32820 25.25434)";
DbGeography myLocation = DbGeography.PointFromText(format, 4326);
var users = context.Users.Select(u => new
{
    fullName = u.name,
    lat = u.location.Latitude,
    lng = u.location.Longitude,
    distance = myLocation.Distance(u.location)
}).ToList();

//distance: 7142.949659532529
```

Also you should check those locations inserted in the `Users` table. Make sure when inserting they have been correctly inserted. Otherwise they will be somewhere else not the location of your `Users`

**More**:

```
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::Point(25, 55 ,4326).Lat                       //25

DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(25  55)", 4326).Latitude.Value //55

Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.STPointFromText(
            new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars("POINT(25 55)"), 4326).Lat.Value;
                                                                //55
```

**What is WKT and where does it come from?**
It's a **W**ell-**K**nown **T**ext representation of different geometry types that is introduce by OGC in the [Simple Feature Access](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) specification and all software vendors are advised to follow it in the sake of the compatibility. This specification shows us how to define point, line (linestring), polygon and some other geometry types as text (WKT) and binary (WKB).

SQL Server do not completely follow this specification and we see the result of not following standards, causes such problems in different components of even the same company.

Answer (score 4):

Switch the Lat/Lng in in API Version.  In the API, it should go Lng Lat

```
select geography::Point(25.3132666, 55.2994054 ,4326).STDistance(geography::Point(25.25434, 55.32820,4326))  as Distance
```

**Returns**

```
7142.94965953253
```

This is where I flipped one Lat/Lng usinq my UDF

```
Select [dbo].[udf-Geo-Meters](55.2994054,25.3132666  ,25.25434,55.32820)
```

**Returns**

```
4135883.9028193
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is very minor but tricky

***SQL SERVER Query***

```
geography::Point(25.3132666, 55.2994054 ,4326)
```

SQL Server defines a point such that first value is latitude and second value is longitude.

***Web API***

```
String format = "POINT(25.25434 55.32820)";
DbGeography myLocation = DbGeography.FromText(format);
```

C# defines a point from above format in such a way that first value is longitude and second value is latitude